# PHP parse xml to array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, api, simplexml

i need to convert an xml to array.
I get the xml from an online api.
My code so far:

```
function download_page($path){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
$retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
curl_close($ch);
return $retValue;
}
$sXML = download_page('https://url/api/user/distgroup/domain/user?t=ticketofuser');
echo "xml start: ". htmlentities($sXML);
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);

echo "xml: ". $oXML;
foreach($oXML["distributionGroups"] as $key=>$value)
{
  $groups[$key]["group"]["id"]=$value["id"];
    $groups[$key]["group"]["domain"]=$value["domain"];
    $groups[$key]["group"]["name"]=$value["name"];
    $groups[$key]["group"]["type"]=$value["type"];
    $groups[$key]["group"]["loggedIn"]=$value["loggedIn"];
    $groups[$key]["group"]["nightMode"]=$value["nightMode"];

    $groups[$key]["group"]["loggedInAgents"]=$value["loggedInAgents"];
    $groups[$key]["group"]["freeAgents"]=$value["freeAgents"];
    $groups[$key]["group"]["callsWaiting"]=$value["callsWaiting"];
}
$temp=array();
    foreach ($groups as $key => $row) {
         $temp[$key]  = $row["id"]; 
}
    array_multisort($temp, SORT_ASC, $groups);
    $_SESSION["groups"]=$groups;

    echo "groups: ". $groups;
```

Afterdownloaded the xml it looks like this when i echo it with htmlentities($sXML);

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<distributionGroups>
<group>
<id>33247</id>
<domain>soluno.se</domain>
<name>Kamoda Support</name>
<type>ATTENDANT</type>
<loggedIn>true</loggedIn>
<nightMode>false</nightMode>
<loggedInAgents>1</loggedInAgents>
<freeAgents>1</freeAgents>
<callsWaiting>0</callsWaiting>
</group>
<group>
<id>33257</id>
<domain>soluno.se</domain>
<name>Test 5</name>
<type>ATTENDANT</type>
<loggedIn>false</loggedIn>
<nightMode>false</nightMode>
<loggedInAgents>0</loggedInAgents>
<freeAgents>0</freeAgents>
<callsWaiting>0</callsWaiting>
</group>
</distributionGroups>
```

My problem is that my array is empty after my try to foreach fill the array.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second foreach, you are missing the key `group`. Also, you could use `$oXML->group` to iterator over the XML elements:

```
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);
$groups = [] ;
foreach($oXML->group as $group)
{
    $groups[]["group"] = [
        'id' => (string)$group->id,
        'domain' => (string) $group->domain,
        'name' => (string) $group->name,
        'type' => (string) $group->type,
        'loggedIn' => (string) $group->loggedIn,
        'nightMode' => (string) $group->nightMode,
        'loggedInAgents' => (string) $group->loggedInAgents,
        'freeAgents' => (string) $group->freeAgents,
        'callsWaiting' => (string) $group->callsWaiting,
    ];
}
$temp=array();
foreach ($groups as $key => $row) {
    $temp[$key]  = $row['group']["id"]; // missing 'group' in $row['group']
}
array_multisort($temp, SORT_ASC, $groups);

print_r($temp);
print_r($groups);
```

Output of `$temp`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 33247
    [1] => 33257
)
```

Output of `$groups`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [group] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 33247
                    [domain] => soluno.se
                    [name] => Kamoda Support
                    [type] => ATTENDANT
                    [loggedIn] => true
                    [nightMode] => false
                    [loggedInAgents] => 1
                    [freeAgents] => 1
                    [callsWaiting] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [group] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 33257
                    [domain] => soluno.se
                    [name] => Test 5
                    [type] => ATTENDANT
                    [loggedIn] => false
                    [nightMode] => false
                    [loggedInAgents] => 0
                    [freeAgents] => 0
                    [callsWaiting] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Or you could remove `"group"` in your first array :

```
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);
$groups = [] ;
foreach($oXML->group as $group)
{
    $groups[] = [
        'id' => (string)$group->id,
        'domain' => (string) $group->domain,
        'name' => (string) $group->name,
        'type' => (string) $group->type,
        'loggedIn' => (string) $group->loggedIn,
        'nightMode' => (string) $group->nightMode,
        'loggedInAgents' => (string) $group->loggedInAgents,
        'freeAgents' => (string) $group->freeAgents,
        'callsWaiting' => (string) $group->callsWaiting,
    ];
}
$temp=array();
foreach ($groups as $key => $row) {
    $temp[$key]  = $row["id"];
}
array_multisort($temp, SORT_ASC, $groups);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it more flexible by getting the code to copy across each element within the group, adding an element to the array with the element name.  This means that as the XML changes (or if) then the code will still retain all of the data being passed over.

I've also merged the two loops, so that $temp is set in the same loop as the main data.

```
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);
$groups = array();
$temp=array();
foreach ( $oXML->group as $group )  {
    $data = array();
    foreach ( $group as $element )  {
        $data[ $element->getName() ] = (string)$element;
    }
    $groups[]["group"] = $data;
    $temp[] = $data["id"];
}
print_r($temp);
print_r($groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

`new SimpleXMLElement($sXML)` creates an object (not an array) of an XML element. So in your case, this `$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);` gives you the distributionGroups element. From there you can access its child elements like `foreach($oXML->group as $group)`, but remember that `$group` would also be an instance of `SimpleXMLElement()`. To access the content of the element you actually need to cast the object, i.e. `(int) $group->loggedInAgents`, to get an integer value. Otherwise `$group-> loggedInAgents` will actually give you another `SimpleXMLElement()` object, rather than a variable.

read more in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)